# What Open Source Libraries are available (and compile) on PIC Micro devices?

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, pic

I do some hobby work with PIC Microcontrollers and I really enjoy using them because they are cheap and perfect for the applications that I use them for. However, it has become increasingly apparent that I do not know what open source libraries will actually compile for the PIC Micro devices.

Obviously there are the whole set of example code that Microchip themselves release; though that is not quite Open Source.

And there are example projects around the web that may have reusable code but what I am talking about is large projects, like maybe mp3 encoders/decoders written in C that will work with a PIC Micro C compiler.

I am looking for suggested projects that will work. Does anybody know any open source C (or otherwise) projects that will compile on PIC Micro devices?

Comment: "PIC Micro C compiler" Who publishes this compiler? Did you mean the mikroC compiler published by MikroElektronika?

Comment: @Nick: I mean the C18 PIC Micro C compiler that is released by Microchip themselves. (http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014)

Comment: I was going to recommend the Microchip's own forum http://www.microchip.com/forums , but you have already mirrored this thread there.  PIC culture is fragmented by different compilers and a lack of standartization.  Codez written for one compiler (e.g. CCS, which has a good code reuse movement) aren't always easy to port to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the open source Small Device C Compiler (sdcc) for my PIC stuff.  It also supports a variety of microcontrollers.  A lot easier for a hobbyist to stomach than most of the other (expensive) options.

I do my PIC stuff under Ubuntu linux.  There are a number of cool tools available (such as piklab, gpsim, etc.) as well as linux drivers for the Microchip programmers.  I had to create a custom programmer profile in piklab, as my particular programmer is newer than those piklab supports.

You can find routines here and there for doing particular operations, such as addressing an LCD display, but I am not aware of any libraries where these sorts of things have been consolidated.

I imagine that something as complex as an MP3 player would be hard to fit into most PICs due to the limited RAM, if not impossible.  Of course someone may prove me wrong on this...